# Not able to clean out old kernel files in /boot

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

I am trying to Update my server

```
navin@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When i tried with the apt-get -f install

```
navin@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get -f install linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
fdutils linux-doc-3.2.0 linux-source-3.2.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/38.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 150 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 147902 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic (from .../linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic_3.2.0- 67.101_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic_3.2.0-   67.101_amd64.deb (--unpack):
failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-67-generic': No space left on device
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg-deb: error: subprocess   paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
  Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-67-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-67-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-67-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-67-generic
 Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic_3.2.0-67.101_amd64.deb
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When i tried to remove the clean out old kernel files in /boot

```
root@ubuntu: apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Please provide some solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the main problem:

```
No space left on device
```

It's your `/boot` partition that has no more space left. Try to do this:

Delete the unused kernel images manually. But, **take care** to not delete the used one or you will not be able to boot anymore. Type `uname -r` in a terminal. All that contains this version string must not be deleted.

When you cleaned the boot partition, use `apt-get -f install linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic` again.

Then update your system cleanly with:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: navin@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get remove linux-image-2.6.32-40-generic
[sudo] password for navin:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: I am not able to remove the old kernel files

Comment: That's why I wrote **manually** in my answer. remove them by `rm /boot/vmlinuz-[here_old_unused_kernel_version]-generic` and also the initrd: `rm /boot/initrd.img-[here_old_unused_kernel_version]-generic`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to install [**Ubuntu tweak**](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) and remove old kernels through it.

It does it automatically for you.

You have to go to **Janitor** tab and select **old kernel**.

Then hit **clean** button and you are ready...  :)

Comment: I am using a server